# Меню на Java

Tags: java

Всем доброго времени суток! Пишу приложение на Java. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на пункты menubar не появлялось выпадающее меню, а например выполнялась какая-нибудь функция?

Answer (score 1):

Это довольно странная идея. Обычно так не делают, потому что это не user-friendly, так что я не советую вам вообще делать это. Но если вам правда ОЧЕНЬ сильно хочется, то вы можете положить в menu bar прямо menu item и задать ему action. Правда этот menu item будет выглядеть иначе, чем остальные пункты, с чем вам придётся бороться.

Comment: "не user-friendly" - уверен что пункты меню "update", "refresh", "save" с вами не согласятся :)
стоит добавить что в эклипс при вызове пункта меню апдейт и скрытом прогрес баре сам апдейт происходит в фоновом режиме практически без взаимодействия с юзером.
просто для этого пункта меню нужно сделать обработчик 

(хотя сама мысль о том что вы будете выполнять какую-то функцию типа апдейт вместо того чтоб вывести список подменю уже само по себе странно, скорее за все у вас серьезная проблема с дизайном программы. я бы посмотрел как это сделано в промышленых продуктах)

Comment: Пункты "update", "refresh", "save" находятся не на первом уровне.. они сами являются пунктами меню, а не главной строки меню.